# Creating a #define for the pointer asterisk

Tags: c++, c

I am working on an API that, I think, dates from the 80s and the original architect of the API is not working in our company anymore. The API, let's call it ABC API is defined in a public header file `abc.h` that contains following definition:

```
#define ABC_PTR_DECL *
```

and then later in many places in the header file:

```
typedef unsigned char uint8, ABC_PTR_DECL uint8_ptr;
```

The question is, why would someone `#define` the ABC_PTR_DECL and not use the asterisk directly? Are there / were there reasons to have it defined so it can be easily changed in one place?

I'd like to remove this definition in a newer API revisions but I've always wondered why do we have it this way.

Comment: Kill it with fire.

Comment: Careful with tools that generate "stuff" (including docs) from headers/definitions and might use that token for something.

Comment: ... and if, by pure perversity of the universe, there *is* a legitimate problem that this works around, find a better work around and **document its existence and reasons**. Had the original architect done this, you wouldn't have to ask this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only reason that I can think of is that, in the bad old days of MS-DOS and the 286, memory was segmented so sometimes you needed a [far pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_pointer) and sometimes a near pointer. The macro makes it possible to switch the entire codebase from one to the other if the need arises.